# What is the meaning of the phrase いい年こいて?

Tags: slang

> いい年こいて

I understand that toshi means age in this context, but what is a good example of using this in a sentence (informal). What is いい年 in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some facts about いい年:

- Another way of saying いい年 is いい大人　(a good adult).
- いい年こいて is the informal version of  いい年して.

That being said いい年 literally translates to "a good age" which a another way of saying adult or even responsible adult.

いい年こいて can be used in a sentence as follows (Fill the blank with what the person shouldn't be doing):

Whats a good/responsible adult doing ________!?

> Ex: いい年こいて薬やってんじゃんえよ！(what's a responsible adult doing drugs for?)

Comment: can you say いい大人が薬やってんじゃんえよ？

Comment: @DanteGreyson yes. you have to add が　when you say いい大人. Keep in mind the example above is very informal sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, 「いい」, in this context, does not mean "good" at all.  It is being used ironically here to express the person's immatureness.  That person must be doing something that people his/her age would not generally be expected to do.

This usage of 「いい」 is fairly common.  If you need a reference, see the 用法 here:

https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%84-429975#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89

Secondly, the verb 「こく」 is the despising, colloquial form of 「する」, 「言う」, etc.  In this case, it means 「する」.

Hope you can now see the natural collocation of the ironical 「いい」 and the despising 「こく」.